# How can I get paperclip image url in item json data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am going to dispaly json data, i have two model 1) item, 2)image, for image model i attachment peperclip gem.
in place of "image_id":6,in json data i want to display image url

in controller
items_controller.rb

```
class V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
        items = Item.all
        render json: { status: 'success', data: items, status: :ok}



    end


    def show
        item = Item.find(params[:id])
        render json: {status: 'success', data:item, status: :ok}
    end


    private def image_params
       params.permit(:name,:price,:category_id,:image_id,:short_description,:long_description,:is_active,:preparation_time,:serves,:calorie_count,:meal_type_id,:cuisine_id,:spicy_level ,:is_new,:is_bestseller)
    end

end
```

in images_controller.rb

```
class V1::ImagesController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token



    def show
        image = Image.find(params[:id])
        render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok
    end


    def create
        image = Image.new(image_params)
        if image.save
            render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok    
        else
            render json: {status: 'error', message:'image not saved', data:image.errors},status: :unprocessable_entity  
        end 
    end


    def destroy
        image = Image.find(params[:id])
        image.destory
        render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok    
    end

    private def image_params
        params.permit(:item_image,:title,:filename)
    end

end
```

model

item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :images, dependent: :destroy

end
```

image.rb

```
 class Image < ApplicationRecord

    has_attached_file :item_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :item_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    belongs_to :item
end
```

now i am getting json output for item

```
  {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bruschette with Tomato",
            "price": 0,
            "category_id": 10,
            "image_id": 6,
            "short_description": "ut error",
            "long_description": "placeat sit quasi dolorum quia vel consequatur",
            "is_active": true,
            "preparation_time": "2018-12-25 19:30:09 +0530",
            "serves": 1545640612,
            "calorie_count": 465,
            "meal_type_id": 4,
            "cuisine_id": 5,
            "spicy_level": 1,
            "is_new": false,
            "is_bestseller": false,
            "updated_at": "2018-12-25T07:10:16.144Z",
            "created_at": "2018-12-25T07:10:16.144Z"
        }
```

. but in place of "image_id":6,i want to display image url how can i
    do, pls need help......

Comment: You want your Item JSON to have `image_url`. But in your code, one item can have many images. So which `image_url` do you want in the Item JSON?

Answer (score 1):

According to provided association i.e. item has_many images and images belongs_to item, then the reference for items table primary_key should be in image table instead of images table primary_key in items table.

**Find all images of an item using active record association:**

```
@item = Item.find_by(id: params[:id])
@images = @item&.images
```

Instead of returning json from action, return it from jbuilder view. Iterate images array to find and return respective image path under item object.

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder